# how to display graph view inside form view in openerp 7?

Tags: odoo

I am using openerp 7. we can display tree view inside form view. but what if we want to display graph inside form view. i tried to  add graph view in form view but it's give error like "Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!"
so how can i display graph view inside form view ?....thanks

Comment: That's still a wishful thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as current openerp architecture to put to view due to javascript implementation of graph libraries they are using.